# Subnetting an already subnetted address further

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I'm a little lost with a question given by my instructor in class and just wanted some clarification on my work.

The question is -

> Given:
>   IP Address: 133.64.128.0 /24
>   Want: 37 networks
>   Want: What is the 5th network?

I know this is a Class B address so the default subnet mask is a /16, which means that this address is already subnetted. It states that it needs 37 networks, which means I would need to further subnet this to a /30 to get that, but that only leaves me with 2 usable host addresses and it's asking for the 5th network.

Working out the problem I seem to only get these networks and that only amounts to 4.

- 133.64.128.0
- 133.64.128.1
- 133.64.128.2
- 133.64.128.3

Am I missing something really simple or is this a trick question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you "know" is a bit out of date – in modern networks, "already subnetted Class B" no longer has any meaning. If you were given a /24, it's a /24, nothing more or less.

(There is no classful addressing anymore, only CIDR; there is no "class B" nor its default subnet mask, only /24; there are no restrictions in further subdivision of a subnet, because with CIDR there's no real difference between 'net' and 'subnet' anyway.)

That said, you're simply confusing terms in your question:

> Working out the problem I seem to only get these networks

What you listed are *not* networks – a network is a collection of addresses. Those are host addresses *within* a network (specifically, within the 133.64.128.0/30 subnet).

If you divide the given 133.64.128.0/24 network into /30's (taking 6 bits), you get 64 sub-networks:

1. 133.64.128.0/30 (with hosts .0–.3)
2. 133.64.128.4/30 (with hosts .4–.7)
3. 133.64.128.8/30 (with hosts .8–.11)
4. 133.64.128.12/30 (and so on)
5. 133.64.128.16/30
6. 133.64.128.20/30
7. ...and so on.

Since it's asking you for the 5th *network*, the answer would be `133.64.128.16/30`.

Comment: Ah, so it was something stupid and I was overcomplicating things.  Thank you for pointing that out!